# how to count repetitive registers in a column mysql laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, cpu-registers

im new in Laravel and  i want to count repetitive registers in a field name "career" from a table named "students"

Table students

```
career
-------
1
1
2
1

desired output 
---------------

3
1
```

indicating
"three" repetitive ones (1) and
"one" number (2)

i am using $results = DB::select('select * from students', array(1)); to read career field with the output 1121
how can i do in order to count repetitive registers ? anyhelp is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to count all records by grouping the career field, this is more related to mysql here is the fiddle for mysql
[http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b03713/4/0](https://SQL%20fiddle)

it'll give you following records

[image]
for Laravel you can run the following query,

```
$career = DB::table('students')
                 ->select('career', DB::raw('count(*) as registers'))
                 ->groupBy('career')
                 ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, all  the answers are working correctly, but the result $career is an object, is there a way i can get the values 3 1 as a vector without keys? Object.values inside javascript  is not working, i am using Laravel 8, Thank you very much for support

Comment: after getting records in Laravel `get` method you should traverse the `$career` object with `array_values($career)` you'll get only keys.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the raw MySQL query you want:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM students
GROUP BY career
ORDER BY career;
```

It should be straightforward to figure out how to port the above to Laravel code.

Comment: tested and working exactly how the OP wants it. just the typo: `ORDER BY cnt DESC`

Comment: Thank you very much, this code is working perfectly, but cnt is an Object, is there a way i can get the output values as a vector with out keys?, Object.values inside javascript is not working, i am using Laravel 8, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
 $results = DB::table("students")
            ->select("count (*) as cnt")
            ->where(DB::raw("career"))
            ->groupBy("career")
            ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the answer is correctly and is working fin, is there a way i can get the output values as a vector with out keys?, Object.values inside javascript is not working, i am using Laravel 8, Thank you very much for the support given